# hardware and tehnology for authorization of vehicles on acces parking

Tags: hardware, authentication

In our company we have a parking lot with small our parking manager software,
Beside regular customers witch at enter on parking taking pappier note bill with barcode
witch they will use at exit when they are paying parking.
We also have tenantry which is allowed to enter and exit parking freely.
So,I need to be able to control them and for that I need in some way to register vehicles on enter and also at exit.
When We were set it up it used magnetic card readers and magnetic card for each owner,
But that combination do not seems to work all time well, a lot of people have troubles when they using theirs cards, (deferent way of puling car trough card reader, lot of drives do not stop close enough to can reach card reader, card reader do not work well at low temperatures and lot of similar things).

Now I planing to modernize equipment for authorization users, and also asking you to give me
a direction and suggestion what hardware and technology should I use for this and where I can by aforesaid.

Both of terminals are very close to one central server, so interface for devices is not important.

Ill love to try [Automatic number plate recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_number_plate_recognition) or wireless magnetic cards or something other like keyboard dial set for entering a code.

We do not have a lot of resource for that, because We have only about 100 customers of monthly parking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither automatic plate recognition nor RFID car tags are ready for small-business deployment.  Last year, we tried to do auto plate recognition at one facility of ours, and never got it to work properly.  We tried earlier this year to use RFID tags on the car windows at one of our facilities, and have not yet had it work reliably.

One relatively easy upgrade might be to [proximity cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_card) instead of magnetic cards.  There is no contact needed between the reader and the card.  My company uses prox cards for the parking area and the office, and mine stays in my wallet.  I still have to drive close enough to open my window, but I don't have to insert the card, just wave it close to the reader.

Comment: The other good thing about proximity/RFID cards is that if you already have one (e.g. I was issued one to make the lifts in our building work after-hours) you can usually get other systems to recognise it. So rather than have five cards, you just have one card registered on multiple systems.

Answer (score 1):

Wow...no really, wow.

Anyway - as far as I know automatic plate recognition systems are pretty expensive ($20k-$50k each) - does your business-model allow for such costs before we get into the technical details? The reason I ask is that your costs are sunk already it seems, where's the revenue coming to pay for the investment?

Comment: unfortunately, We do not have so big budget for buying ANPR for 10k and more $). Thats way I asked this question, I got a platy of suppliers for many kind of solutions from cheap magnetic readers of 100$ up to as you mentioned 50k$, I also heard from (so I call them peanuts programmers) that they can do It using 2 web cams in C# fro less then one day coding.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into RFID access cards.  A gated apartment complex I lived in once issued them to residents and we would just wave the card in front of the sensor when we pulled up to the gate and it would open.

Data centers also use these for controlled access to secure areas in some cases.

Having said that, this isn't really so much a sysadmin question as it is a facilities question.

Comment: regarding to your PS, it is not truly sysadmin question but doing this job I used to be from teacher of setting up boss's daughter MSN up to making deals for buying equipment of millions and also fighting with SQL-s and Novells. When I asked this I have on my mind that same fortune whit me dealing a lot of US.